# Difference between then and then begin?

Tags: delphi

I am pretty new at coding and have no idea the benefits/drawbacks/differences between `then *insert code*` and `then begin *insert code*`.

```
if ... then
...

if ... then
begin
```

Comment: `begin` starts a new statement block. If the condition evaluates to `true`, everything between `begin` and `end` will be executed. Without `begin` (and the later `end`), only the first statement after `then` will be executed. This is basic Delphi/Pascal BTW. It is great that you are trying things out, but if you don't mind my saying so, I think you would benefit from some formal instruction in the language. You may benefit from a beginner's book or course about the language.

Comment: [Declarations and Statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi))

Comment: You can always use the begin/end format, even if it contains just a single line, but for multiple lines begin/end is always required. It is a matter of style, but for me I *always* use begin/end even when it is not strictly necessary, both because I find it easier to read and because I find it easier to maintain when I am changing from a single line to multiple lines in later development.

Answer (score 7):

Delphi needs `begin` and `end` to form blocks. It does not keep blocks of code together by indentation, like e.g. Python does, it uses `begin` `end` to delineate these blocks. Languages like C, C++, C#, Java and JavaScript use `{` and `}` instead, for the same purpose.

In Pascal, the *if-statement* is as follows:

```delphi
if <condition> then operation1
```

or, if there is an *else-clause*:

```delphi
if <condition> then operation1 else operation2
```

*Where `<condition>` can be any expression that has a boolean result*

The operation can be a single statement, e.g.

```delphi
Writeln('Hello')
```

or it can be a so called *compound statement*, which is a begin-end block with multiple statements inside (although zero or one statements are also allowed), e.g.:

```delphi
begin
  Writeln('Hello');
  Writeln('World!')
end
```

So the difference is not between `then` and `then begin`, but between **single statements** and **compound statements**. An, admittedly rather simple, example:

```delphi
if NeedOneLine then
  Writeln('Hello, World!') // single statement
else
begin                      // compound statement: multiple statements enclosed 
  Writeln('Hello,');       // in "begin" and "end"
  Writeln('World!');
end;
```

The above code either writes one line or two lines. The following code, that does not use begin end, looks similar, but has a totally different result:

```delphi
if NeedOneLine then
  Writeln('Hello, World!') 
else
  Writeln('Hello,');
  Writeln('World!');
```

That will either write `'Hello, World!'` or `'Hello,'` and **always be followed by** `'World!'`, because it is **exactly** the same as:

```delphi
if NeedOneLine then
  Writeln('Hello, World!') 
else
  Writeln('Hello,');
Writeln('World!');
```

In other words, the last line is not part of the if-statement anymore and will be executed unconditionally. That is why `begin` and `end` are important here.